# Add Wordpress comment count

Tags: wordpress, count, comments

I have a page with a loop that lists all it's child categories with the category description, post count and the last published post date.

```
Child category name                     post count   comment count    pubdate
Child category description                   5            xxx            

• last published post in cat
• second last published post in cat
```

I accomplish this with this piece of PHP.

```
<?php $categories =  get_categories('child_of=225');

 foreach  ($categories as $category) {
    //Display the sub category information using $category values like $category->cat_name
     echo '<div class="row clearfix">';
     echo '<div class="col1"><div class="inner"><h2>'.$category->name.'</h2>';
     echo '<p>'.$category->description.'</p>';
     echo '<p class="recent"><strong>Meest recent:</strong></p>';
     echo '<ul class="recentlist">';

     foreach (get_posts('posts_per_page=2&cat='.$category->term_id) as $post) {
         setup_postdata( $post );
         $my_date = mysql2date('D j M Y', $post->post_date);

         $commentcount = ;

     echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';

echo '</div></div>'; //end .col1 .inner

echo '<div class="col2">'.$category->count.'</div>';

echo '<div class="col3">'.$commentcount.'</div>';

echo '<div class="col4">'.$my_date.'</div></div>';

} ?>
```

I can't seem to get the comment count working. I know the syntax needs work... im working on that.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Cheers, 
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something in your code, the `$commentcount` variable is not feeded with any output from any function.

Have you tried the standard approach yet?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_number

Comment: I know, its just the place where i ment to add the code for it. And eerhm... sorry I don't know how I could've missed out on that piece of wp codex.

Answer (score 0):

```
$commentcount = get_comments_number( $post->ID );
```

This should retrieve the total number of comments in that post.